mysql workbench 8.0.36 does not work under osx14
Apple M1 Pro (OSX 14.5)
Mysql Workbench 8.0.36
When I open the table editor, I can't edit the table name or close this editing panel.
I've tried versions 8.0.31 through 8.0.35 and they all do the same thing, too low of a version and it even crashes!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!



Have you submitted a bug report?

Bugs have been fixed in version 8.0.38

I faced a similar problem but this worked:
I installed version 8.0.34 for the workbench and 8.0.37 for the server
